# Iteratee function loses reference to this object in javascript if used with bluebird map function

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I am using bluebird npm package for handling asynchronous workloads in my application. Lets assume that `processAllItems` function is used to trigger processing of all the items. Each one of the items from the list, needs to be processed using function `processOneItem` which processes them one by one. It internally calls few functions from the same class. Bluebird library's `.map` function  is used to manage concurrency of execution here. So, my code looks something like this.

```
const Bluebird = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function (app) {
  return {

    doSomething: function () {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // do something and resolve
      });
    },

    processOneItem: function (item) {
      let self = this;
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // blah
        self.doSomething()  //self is undefined
          .then(function () {
            //do something else and so on...
          })
      });
    },

    processAllItems: function () {
      const self = this;
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // processOneItem function is to be called for an array of data
        // lets assume
        let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        Bluebird.map(array, self.processOneItem, { concurrency: 5 })
          .then(function () {
            return resolve();
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            return reject(error);
          });

      });
    }
  };
};
```

Since functions `doSomething`, `processOneItem` and `processAllItems` are keys of the same object, they need to be accessed by the `this` object, which is assigned to `self` variable. This all makes sense from javascript perspective so far. But when I execute this code, I get error saying `Cannot read property 'doSomething'` on line  `self.doSomething()` inside function `processOneItem`. How is it possible that the reference to `this` object is lost? Am I doing something wrong here?

One thing I noticed, if I wrap the iteratee function inside another unnamed function, this seems to work perfectly fine.

```
const Bluebird = require('bluebird');

module.exports = function (app) {
  return {

    doSomething: function () {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // do something and resolve
      });
    },

    processOneItem: function (item) {
      let self = this;
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // blah
        self.doSomething()  //self reference is maintained, works perfectly fine.
          .then(function () {
            //do something else and so on...
          })
      });
    },

    processAllItems: function () {
      const self = this;
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        // processOneItem function is to be called for an array of data
        // lets assume
        let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
        Bluebird.map(array, function (record) { return self.processOneItem(record); }, { concurrency: 5 })
          .then(function () {
            return resolve();
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            return reject(error);
          });

      });
    }
  };
};
```

How is it possible that when the line

```
Bluebird.map(array, self.processOneItem, { concurrency: 5 })
```

is replaced with line

```
Bluebird.map(array, function (record) { return self.processOneItem(record); }, { concurrency: 5 })
```

the reference to `this` object is maintained inside the iteratee function and code works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of javascript binding.  Here is a simplification of your case above that yield the same result regardless of bluebird.

```
const obj = {
    a: function(){
        console.log('A THIS!', this)
    },
    
    b: function(){
        console.log('B THIS!', this)
    }

}

function c_function(paramsFunction){
    paramsFunction();
}


obj.a() // A THIS!, {a: function(), b: function()}
obj.b() // b THIS!, {a: function(), b: function()}

c_function(obj.a) //"A THIS!" global {Buffer: function(), clearImmediate: function(), clearInterval: function(), clearTimeout: function(), …}


c_function(function() { obj.a()}) // A THIS!, {a: function(), b: function()}
```

The `this` of the javascript for a function execution is binded at the execution of that function.

1. List item

So when calling

```
obj.a()
```

It check for the this rules and find it was called on an object so the `this` will be `obj`.

2. When calling

```
c_function(obj.a)
```

c_function receive a function as an argument.  When it execute the function it try to bind the this.  As c_function scope is concerned, the function is not called on an object.  Therefore it will bind the this according to the rules.  Here `c_function` is binded to the `global this` and executing `paramsFunction()` the binding will be the same.

3. When calling

```
c_function(function() { obj.a()}) // Or
c_function(() => { obj.a()})
```

All the knowledge of the 2 previous are combine.  The important takeaway is that at the moment of the call you are calling from `obj`

**EXTRA**
Note that the map function may call your function with a `bind`, `call` or `apply`.  This will affect the scope of the executed function.

```
function c_function_binding(paramsFunction) {
    paramsFunction.call({}, paramsFunction)
}

c_function_binding(obj.a) // "A THIS!" {}
```

I was not able to find it, but a few years ago Kyle Simpson had a course or a workshop that explained in detail the scope binding in javascript and all its quirks.